# java if numbers are within interval

Tags: java

I have simple text file which looks something like this:

```
2-4
3-8
5-6
1-9
```

I want to check if passed numbers are within these intervals. Currently I have something like this:

```
int first = 2; //passed to the method
int second = 4; // passed to the method

while ((newLine = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] result = newLine.split("-");

    int numberOne = Character.getNumericValue(result[0]);
    int numberTwo = Character.getNumericValue(result[1]);

    if ((first >= numberOne && first <= numberTwo) && (second >= numberOne && second <= numberTwo)) {
        System.out.println("Numbers are between " + numberOne + " and " + numberTwo);
    }
}
```

Now it would print result like this:

```
Numbers are between 2 and 4
Numbers are between 1 and 9
```

What I would like to be printed is only this: `Numbers are between 2 and 4`.

Here would be some more examples:

```
passing 1 and 2 would print out: Numbers are between 1 and 9
passing 5 and 6 would print out: Numbers are between 5 and 6
passing 4 and 8 would print out: Numbers are between 3 and 8
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: So, tell us what's the idea behind? You only want to get the first result? How about a `break` statement in the `if`?

Comment: The easiest way will be to store your intervals in an array and sort them in the sequence you want it to return - from narrowest to widest. Then iterate over these array elements and compare your input(s) to lower and upper values, if they fit exit the iteration.

Comment: It is not clear, what your algorithm should do - it's perfectly right that it prints out all valid ranges, since 2 and 4 are both between 2 and 4 and between 1 and 9.

Comment: Your question makes sense and the algorithm seems to be correct although not efficient, but what exactly is your question not that we know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "I want to check if passed numbers are within these intervals."  Congratulations, that is what your code is doing now.  However, it isn't clear what you're asking to change it to.  Are you only trying to return the *first* match? Or the *best* match? P.S. - this totally sounds like a CS homework assignment.

Comment: I want to return as you said "best match". It's not any homework, just trying to learn something!

Comment: When you are looking for a "best match" then the order of your intervals is very important. Also there might be more than one "best match". What about the intervals `[1-3] and [2-4]` and the input values `2 and 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If input is sorted, you only need to **break** the loop on valid result.

Else, you store all your valid results in a List and after the end of the loop you just select the smallest range in the list of result.

```
...
    List<int[]> resultList = new ArrayList<int[]>
    while ((newLine = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] result = newLine.split("-");
        int numberOne = Character.getNumericValue(result[0]);
        int numberTwo = Character.getNumericValue(result[1]);
        if ((first >= numberOne && first <= numberTwo) && (second >= numberOne && second <= numberTwo)) {
            resultList.add(new int[2]{numberOne,nunumberTwo});
        }
    }
    if(!resultList.isEmpty()){
        int[] smallestInterval = null;
        int minInterval = 0;
        for(int[] result : resultList){
            int inerval = result[1]-result[0]
            if(smallestInterval==null || inerval < smallestInterval){
                minInterval = inerval;
                smallestInterval= result;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Numbers are between " + smallestInterval[0] + " and " + smallestInterval[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you check condition is fine.
Only you need to break; from the loop once you find the matching numbers between which the provided value lies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should print only the first line.

```
if ((first >= numberOne && first <= numberTwo) && (second >= numberOne && second <=     numberTwo)) {
        System.out.println("Numbers are between " + numberOne + " and " + numberTwo);
        break;
}
```